# extjs add vertical scrollbar to grid

Tags: extjs, grid

I am trying to add a scrollbar to my extjs and can't seem to figure it out.
From what I have researched people seem to say its usually a bad layout in my design.  Can someone please point me in the right direction to allow scrolling?

I have an hbox with 3 grids... the middle one is the issue DETAILS GRID that doesn't show a scroll bar when the data is populated

```
      {
        layout: 'hbox',
        flex: 1,
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Account Summary',
                xtype: 'grid',
                id: 'summaryGridID',
                bind: {
                    store: '{myAccountSummaryStore}',
                    selection: '{selectedManager}'
                },
                flex: 1.50,
                forceFit: true,
                //height: 200,
                listeners: {
                    itemClick: 'onSelectionChange'
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        header: 'AcctNum',
                        dataIndex: 'AcctNum'
                        //maxWidth: 80
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'AcctName',
                        dataIndex: 'AcctShortCode'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Daily P&L',
                        dataIndex: 'CalcPLSett',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            var calc = value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
                            if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = "$" + calc;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Daily Pct',
                        dataIndex: 'CalcPLPct',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            var calc = (value * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
                            if (value === "Infinity") {
                                newVal = "0.00%";
                            } else if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + calc + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + calc + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = calc;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'splitter'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'grid',
                id: 'detailsGridID',
                bind: {
                    store: '{myDetailsStore}'
                },
                title: 'Details',
                flex: 3,
                forceFit: true,
                //overflowY: 'scroll',
                //autoScroll: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        header: 'Market',
                        dataIndex: 'FullMarketName',
                        width: 225
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Last',
                        dataIndex: 'LastPrice',
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Delta',
                        dataIndex: 'Delta',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            newVal = value.toFixed(3);
                            if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + newVal + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + newVal + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = newVal;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Prev Pos',
                        dataIndex: 'PrevPos',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + value + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + value + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = value;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Prev P&L',
                        dataIndex: 'PrevPL',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            var calc = value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
                            if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = "$" + calc;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Top Trd',
                        dataIndex: 'TopTrd',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + value + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + value + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = value;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Top P&L',
                        dataIndex: 'TopPL',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            var calc = value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
                            if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = "$" + calc;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Net Pos',
                        dataIndex: 'NetPos',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + value + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + value + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = value;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Net P&L',
                        dataIndex: 'NetPL',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            var calc = value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
                            if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = "$" + calc;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'splitter'
            },
            {
                title: 'Sector Summary',
                xtype: 'grid',
                id: 'sectorGridID',
                bind: {
                    store: '{mySectorSummaryStore}',
                    selection: '{selectedSector}'
                },
                flex: 1.50,
                forceFit: true,
                //height: 200,
                listeners: {
                    itemClick: 'onSectorSelectionChange'
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        header: 'Sector',
                        dataIndex: 'Sector'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Position',
                        dataIndex: 'Position',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            var calc = value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
                            if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + calc + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + calc + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = calc;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'P&L',
                        dataIndex: 'CalcPL',
                        renderer: function (value) {
                            var newVal;
                            var calc = value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
                            if (value > 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                            } else if (value < 0) {
                                newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                newVal = "$" + calc;
                            }
                            return newVal;
                        },
                        align: 'right'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

THIS IS THE LAYOUT OF THE OVERALL PANEL

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.view.clientdetails.clientdetails',{
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

alias: 'widget.clientdetails',

itemId: 'clientDetailsItemID',

reference: 'clientDetailsPanel',

id: 'clientDetailsViewID',

requires: [
    'ExtApplication1.view.clientdetails.clientdetailsController',
    'ExtApplication1.view.clientdetails.clientdetailsModel'
],

controller: 'clientdetails-clientdetails',

viewModel: {
    type: 'clientdetails-clientdetails'
},

layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    pack: 'start',
    align: 'stretch'
},
items: [
    {
        layout: 'hbox',
        height: 50,
    items:
},
    {
        layout: 'hbox',
        height: 50,
    items:
},
    {
        layout: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch',
        flex: 1,
        items: [
THIS IS IS THE AREA WITH THE 3 GRIDS.
THE MIDDLE GRID IS THE ONE THAT I AM TRYING TO HAVE A SCROLLBAR

]
```

Comment: I tried adding autoScroll: true.. did not work

Comment: I am not able to generate your problem. I have prepared this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ass using your code. And grid is scrollable by default.

Comment: The code you've posted isn't really relevant because all you show is the grid. The relevant part for the layout is what is surrounding the grid. Also, that copy and paste in the renderer...

Comment: I've added the hbox that the problem grid sits in... the grid in question is the middle one.  Is that enough layout or should I show more?

Comment: As I said above, the grid itself isn't really relevant. Where are the grids getting a height from in the layout?

Comment: ahhh okay sorry.  I added the code above... where I believe the grids are getting their height

Comment: I don't see where the grids get a height from. The `hbox` containing the 3 grids gets a height by virtue of being `flex: 1` (assuming it's being contained in something appropriate). But then you have a `hbox` layout and without `align: stretch` and the grids don't have an explicit height defined.

Comment: that is correct.  I never explicitly say height is x.  What I was trying to do was basically make that last hbox stretch vertically to fill the screen.  Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: As I said above, you don't have an `align: stretch` on the `hbox`. You're already using it for the `vbox`, so I assumed you know what it was for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112786/discussion-between-solarissf-and-evan-trimboli).

Comment: I found if I put autoScroll:true on the hbox holding all the items, a scrollbar appears, but one bar on all 3 grids in the hbox.  I want an individual scrollbar on a single grid.  any ideas?

Comment: As I said above. You need to give the grid a height. Use align stretch on the hbox to stretch the grids vertically to the size of the container.

Comment: I gave the hbox align: 'stretch' and still nothing --- edited code above

Comment: FINALLY got it... I had to add height: '100%' to the grid, thanks for all the help